# How can I force Workrave to start in Normal mode?

Tags: autostart, workrave

I use Workrave for RSI prevention and rest breaks. [*] Sometimes I need to put it in Quiet or Suspended mode, for example when giving a presentation. However, it remembers this setting the next time I log in, and I might forget to put it back.

How can I make Workrave always start in Normal mode?

[*] It starts up every time I log in, but I can't remember/find how I did this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workrave does not have this functionality built-in. Instead, you will have to create a trigger to achieve this. You can do this by adding the following command to Startup Applications:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.workrave.Workrave /org/workrave/Workrave/Core org.workrave.CoreInterface.SetOperationMode string:'normal'
```

Regarding login behaviour, Workrave always starts when you log in, there is no option for it to do otherwise. You could achieve the *effect* of it not starting by setting it to Suspended on startup:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.workrave.Workrave /org/workrave/Workrave/Core org.workrave.CoreInterface.SetOperationMode string:'suspended'
```

(Note I am using [Cuttlefish](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cuttlefish/) (see also [Launchpad project](https://launchpad.net/cuttlefish)) to make these calls rather than Startup Applications, but the results should be the same.)

---

There are existing requests to implement this functionality:

- [Force Workrave mode on startup](http://issues.workrave.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138)
- [Make Workrave startup optional](http://issues.workrave.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1137)

---

**Alternatives**

In theory you can also use `dconf` to set these values as follows (0 - Normal, 1 - Suspended, 2 - Quiet):

```
dconf write /org/workrave/general/operation-mode 0
```

However, there is a bug preventing this from working in Workrave 1.10.2.0. This [has been fixed](https://github.com/rcaelers/workrave/commit/3c386043f489fc2ff9f449d612ef279d0fe0df73) for the next release.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly workrave doesn't have such option. You should find out where you put the autostart and disable it (or just remember that you have it):

> OPTIONS
>
> Workrave does not take any options besides the standard GNOME options.

(workrave man)

Comment: it looks like you can use gsettings or ~/.workrave/workrave.ini to set/store settings - I'm thinking I can write a script - but I haven't found a definitive list of settings yet

Answer (score 0):

Is so simple, I crossed for the same, you have to remember that the icon changes, you will not see the sheep, you see something like a door, click on it, and a window will display with many options, click on option mode and change to start.